# Change language to "+2 more" link in react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Im using React Big Calendar and is able to change the language to swedish using  culture="sv-SE" and the buttons using: messages={{next:"xxx",previous:"xxx",today:"xxx"}}.

However, the popup button "+X more" is still in english. is it possible to change that using the message prop or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I passed messages prop to RBC Calendar component like

```
<Calendar
 ...othrer props
 messages={{
          next: 'Следущий',
          previous: 'Предидущий',
          today: 'Сегодня',
          month: 'Месяц',
          week: 'Неделя',
          day: 'День',
          work_week: 'Рабочая неделя',
          allDay: 'Весь день',
          yesterday: 'Вчера',
          tomorrow: 'Завтра',
          noEventsInRange: 'Не найдено никаких мероприятий в текущем периоде.',
          showMore: function showMore(total) {
            return '+' + total + 'событий';
          }
}}
/>
```

it is for Russian locale

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import 'moment/locale/sv-SE'
```

Using [the MomentJS library](https://momentjs.com/), you can call the different Moment formats and get your favorite language.